# select one entry sql

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to select just one entry from a database.  It is currently returning an xml document object and I can't figure out why.  Atleast, thats what my javascript is telling me.  I want it to return a string that is the name fo the gameRequestUser where userName="this user"

```
          try {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data asdfasdf;database=asdfsdfdf;User id=asdfasdfasdfPassword=asdfasdf;");

            SqlCommand getRequest = new SqlCommand("SELECT gameRequestUser FROM UserData Where userName='" + Session["userName"].ToString() + "'", conn);

            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = getRequest.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read()) {
                user = reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
            }

            conn.Close();

            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) { return e.Message.ToString(); }
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the "XML document" you think that you are getting?

Comment: You should not show publicly your complete connection string with IP, Username and Password.

Comment: Thanks, forgot.  I have an alert in my $.get statement and it just says XML document object

Comment: You should be using a parameter to set the userName, not inserting the string into the query.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`:

```
user = (string)getRequest.ExecuteScalar();
```

And even before you should check your query results using SQL Server Management Studio - run the query there and check if the results are OK.

Comment: @Steve why you think 'should' is a wrong word here? `ExecuteScalar` is for exactly that kind of queries, so it's a lot better approach then using `SqlDataReader`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek well `should` is imperative, the ExecuteReader works as well, of course, in this case it's better the ExecuteScalar,but I don't see how this should change the result.

Comment: @Steve should != have to :) But that's not important - I'm happy that it worked and question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

Always use parameters, you avoid too many problems (string quote, sql injections etc)

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("yourconnectionstring"))
{
    SqlCommand getRequest = new SqlCommand("SELECT gameRequestUser FROM UserData Where " + 
                                           "userName=@user", conn); 
    conn.Open(); 
    getRequest.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",Session["userName"].ToString()) 
    SqlDataReader reader = getRequest.ExecuteReader(); 
    while (reader.Read()) { 
        user = reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should do is go into SQL Server Management studio, and try running the query there directly:

```
SELECT gameRequestUser FROM UserData Where userName='this user'
```

That being said, another thing to keep in mind is you can tell SQL to return to you at most 1 row by doing something like:

```
SELECT top 1 gameRequestUser FROM UserData Where userName='this user'
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: SqlCommand getRequest = new SqlCommand("SELECT top 1 gameRequestUser FROM UserData Where userName='" + Session["userName"].ToString() + "'", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = getRequest.ExecuteReader();

            reader.Read();
                user = reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a SELECT TOP 1 ... query

   SELECT TOP 1 gameRequestUser FROM UserData WHERE ...
2. Use SqlCommand's ExecuteScalar() method instead of ExecuteReader(), since you only need one field value returned.

   SqlCommand getRequest = new SqlCommand(....);
   ...
   string user = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());